# How would people deny obviously supernatural things in a modern setting?

Tags: society, psychology

So I'm designing a world where monsters from a well-known (in-universe) video game leak into a modern world. The monsters and the local law-enforcement will trade blows, bodies will drop on both sides. (The heroes are a third party here, they aren't "above the law" but the law enforcement doesn't know how to stop them, nor do they want to stop the people fighting the monsters.) The monsters (and some humans, as a result of the anarchy) will basically be involved in terrorism-scale criminal activity.

But the problem is I don't want to handle (A) The possible military implications or (B) the populace at large. The events NEED, to keep my story simple, to be isolated to this one town where the game takes place.

I can't think of an easy way to handle the (quite realistic) concern that police would "call for backup" on a national scale, or that there would be nationwide panic over the brand-new beasts that dwell among us.
I need a conspiratorial level cover-up. Any thoughts?

EDIT: Barring this possibility, how might I keep the military from significantly mucking up my RPG Player party from doing their own poking around? (They're high schoolers.)

Comment: Unless the people you have that are trying to cover it up are more trustworthy to the military than the police, it will be impossible. Also will be videos on the internet within minutes of any of this. Unless you kill everyone before they tell another person, it's just not going to happen.

Comment: You need a way to cut off communications, or put your town under a "dome".

Comment: Not answer, but it may lead someone to an answer: You either need to (1) cut off communication with the rest of the world, or (2) cut off the _desire_ for anybody to communicate with the rest of the world. (Hey, maybe this takes place on an island instead of in a town! Or it could be set a few hundred years ago when instant communication wasn't possible.)

Comment: Are “heroes” and “law enforcement” the same? Your third sentence is confusing.

Comment: Can the monsters induce amnesia, so when the police go back to the station at the end of their shift, they remember having had a rough day, but none of the particulars?

Comment: @Peregrine Rock: The heroes are just a bunch of kids.The law enforcement pursues them, but it doesn't get very far because monsters are in the way.

Comment: I sincerely regret voting to close this question and hope you might consider its improvement.  As written, the question is off-topic because it is about the plot of your story, not world-building.  In other words, how to conspire to cover-up the incursion is not a function of the rules of your world.  For more information, please see our [question FAQ](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: GTA fan: "nice I'm stealing this tank! die monsters..." 25 minutes later... "where's the freaking garage? can't you see this is a tank you stupid cops and stop banging me already."

Comment: `The monsters (...) will basically be involved in terrorism-scale criminal activity.`  Is one of them voiced by john goodman?

Comment: @JBH The non-intervention by national authorities is a rule of how this world functions. This is *not* part of its plot. Plus it's obviously not like our world. The OP is seeking a means how this can happen in his world. That's what worldbuilding is, after all. So it is on-topic.

Comment: @a4android, I posted a [meta question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5581/was-my-choice-about-the-behavior-of-police-not-being-worldbuilding-wrong) to ask for community input as to my reasons to close.

Comment: @JBH Excellent! Throwing an issue like this open for discussion, hopefully, will be beneficial. While I disagree with your reasons, I do applaud the fact that you were prepared to explain what they were, and so bringing clarity and a rationale for your decision. I only wish this happened more often. Yours should be a model to be followed by WBers concerning their VTC's.

Answer (score 16):

I have sometimes wondered - why, when some single medium powered superhero realized he is up against a big deal, does he not call up in in-world heavy hitters from his universe to help?  Answer: the Fantastic 4 and the Avengers are busy saving the world from proportionately greater threats, like Galactus or Thanos.  The local superhero is on his own and has got to make do.

So too your city.  This dimensional leak thing is not something limited to your city only, or certainly the national guard would show up.  But the national guard is busy containing something similar at the capitol, and your local issues can't compete - the locals have to take care of things.

This larger story of nationwide dimensional breaches also offers a narrative thread.  You can drop hints that all is not well.  Maybe some National Guardsmen do show up, tails between their legs.  If your role players do well they may get clues about what is going on in the capitol and possible ways they might be able to set things right there once they level up with the current challenge.

Answer (score 12):

Bureaucracy is your friend. It's known to be slow moving, unimaginative, and skeptical of spending money. So when your little town starts screaming "monsters from a video game are attacking!," your petty bureaucrats are gonna Occam's Razor the heck out of that situation. After all, what's more believable, imaginary monsters came to life, or a town has a gas leak or some mold causing them to hallucinate? Even a terrorist attack is more believable.

So the wheels will start grinding ponderously--send someone out to investigate, possibly send someone else out to investigate the investigators when their stories are unbelievable, then have meetings to decide how best to proceed, etc, etc, etc. You can even get partisan politics involved once it's clear that yes, this is really happening, putting the brakes on rescue operations in the name of "fiscal responsibility," or only sending in half measures that don't really help at all. Played right you could have their help show up just in the heroes darkest hour, or just after it's all resolved, or...never.

As for cover-ups, easy-peasy. Videos will hit Youtube if they have internet, but who in their right mind won't think they're faked? Skeptics will be all over that like white on rice. Any fault in the videos will be seen as evidence it's all faked. People will suspect it's a viral marketing campaign for the game, and the game designers might even take credit--or at least, mysteriously not deny it--because hey, free advertising, and who cares where it comes from?

Those interested in a cover up at upper levels would do well to release truly faked videos to further muddy the waters--we've all seen the court of public opinion, one proven fake must mean all of it is fake. And that's not counting the fakes that the public will do themselves just to mess with people or to see if they can. The real videos can be plastered all over youtube and they'll still be lost in the noise that is the internet.

As for eyewitnesses, get the conspiracy theorists involved. You get enough of the fringe shouting about how this is really, really, *reeeeeally* real and suddenly the news becomes toxic. No self respecting news station will carry it. And that's *before* the conspiracy theorists start adding extraneous things like aliens and chemtrails and FEMA death camps to the mix. Once they start doing that (and they will) the only way anyone will believe this really happened is if someone produced a body, and even then they might be skeptical.

Meanwhile the area goes under quarantine because of drugs/gas leak/really bad fungus/anything that can cause hallucinations and illnesses and could be in the area and that the general public would ***not*** want to get. Make it sound like the least pleasant thing ever (think the Ebola scares) to keep the public away and justify whatever response the military/government *does* manage to send out.

A cover-up these days is easier than getting people to believe something. For those at the top, just play on their lack of empathy--for example: it would cost less to quarantine or bomb the town or just murder everyone in it than to help them, and news of a monster attack might adversely effect the next election since it happened under X's watch (whoever the dominant party is), so let's keep the whole thing on the down low, yeah?

As for the public, keep in mind most news programs these days are corporate and have completely dissolved their investigative news teams. Most newscasters don't even roam far from their offices and rarely leave their home cities. Everything they get is second-hand. They're also easily distracted by a scandal, so have a mass shooting or a violent protest or some politician with his pants down and it'll be all they talk about, effectively burying the news of this one town.

As for the common man, aside from having questionable news sources, they also have skin in the game with being seen a certain way. One of the big ones these days is not being anti-science, so skepticism has practically become a moral imperative. People are happy to tear apart anything unusual or that questions the accepted standard (for example, we still cling firmly to BMI as a health measure despite all kinds of evidence that it's essentially useless), and they'll even disregard real facts in order to be seen in a positive light by others. This behavior is as common for the skeptics and scientists as it is for those of a more...we'll call it an "intellectually creative" mindset and leave it at that.

And this need to be accepted is *really* easy to exploit.

You want to cover up anything, just make it worth more social capital to *not* believe that thing that's happening in front of your face is actually happening in front of your face and people will fall in line.

Comment: This answer relies on myths about bureaucracies. The threat you discuss is exactly the sort of threat that will galvanize any bureaucracy into comprehensive action. Elected officials dread spending money wastefully. In these circumstances, their re-election will be on the line. Money, resources and manpower will flow like wine.

Comment: @a4android yeah, it's probably a myth, but it's a **believable myth**, and that's what counts, here.  :)

Comment: A myth? Five words: gun control laws in America. The problem with bureaucracy is that there is often a push-pull of power with people wanting conflicting actions and results. In America especially (of which I was thinking), government systems were often deliberately *created* to be slow. And yes, if the monsters became world news it may actually galvanize them, maybe. But then again, look at responses to Katrina and Puerto Rico after the hurricanes; sluggish, slap-dash, inefficient, and worse. And no mass shooting has been bad enough to make them move on gun laws. So no, not much of a myth.

Comment: This is pretty much the plot of a great part of "The Master and Margarita" where Satan and a couple of demons personally visit Moscow in the Soviet era, and play a large number of pranks on the citizens. Despite obvious supernatural occurrences, the government is still convinced they are up against some ordinary conmen and tricksters, or at the most, hypnotizers.

Answer (score 8):

That's simple enough.  If it is like a game, then the monsters' corpses vanish into nothing shortly after they are killed.  So there is no direct evidence.  If you were planning on having item drops, you might want to limit them to things like weapons, gold, and ores.  Things that can be explained away.

Then, you make the nature of the portal interfere with attempts to record the monsters.  On film or digital cameras, they look like animals, or humans, or even just blurs.

With no real evidence, it is just written off as gangs and rabid animals.  The police are having problems dealing with it, so they made up these exaggerations and lies to get the military to intervene.

Of course, some people in the government do believe it, but they deny it to avoid a panic, and so that they can experiment on the monsters they have captured.

Comment: Well, that's a problem that I usually have with horror genre - how many deaths (especially deaths among law enforcement) can you have before authorities start to take that seriously? In New York, there is less than one murder per day, in a small town every homicide is a major event, bringing attention of the state police.

Comment: I don't think you even need to interfere with attempts to record the monsters. Just make their skin (fur) look slightly greenish around the edges...

Answer (score 4):

To limit the scope of all activities to just one town, I think several things have to be in place:

1. Physical and informational isolation of the town from rest of civilized world. If your monsters spawn in the middle of New York, or on top of the White House, forget about getting the world to conveniently overlook them. This has to happen in some rural town, preferably some significant distance away from major cities. Communications can be disrupted by some unexplained electromagnetic interference caused by the same portal allowing monsters to come here.
2. Keeping the monsters within the vicinity. If your monsters escape this town and move on to bigger population centres, people will find out. Perhaps have them only appear/ move in the night, and mysteriously dissipate at daybreak? While a common trope, I think it might help pacing somewhat (and in the context of a game, the day hours can be used for a series of sidequests to prepare for the night - think zombie survival games). The furthest that the monsters can wander from your town will then be limited to their speed during the night, and if your town is far enough from everything else, cities will not get to encounter your monsters in the flesh.
3. Government intervention. Of course, authorities will be informed of the situation, but they will realise quickly that it is in the public's best interest for information NOT to get out. Military efforts are focused on containment rather than elimination for starters as scientists are called in to study the situation, while news is released that the town is being used as the set for a new movie - explaining what some people might describe as strange sightings. This gives your protagonists a window of time to do their stuff.
4. BONUS: plot twist - this has actually happened before in another town, but your protagonists did not know because it was covered up too (duh). This helps to explain why the government was able to react so efficiently, and possibly why they were happy to allow a bunch of high-school kids to run around as opposed to conducting a full-scale military operation. Twist v2.0: the initial outbreak was the inspiration for the well-known video game!

Answer (score 2):

**Stranger Things Justified this**

In ST they played with a very similar scenario of how to tell the nation the government was conducting inter dimensional tests resulting in deaths and the invasion of foreign organisms.

The answer is you don't because no one would believe you. Frankly, its hard to believe absurd events occurring let alone dedicate resources to on technically unsubstantiated claims.

**How this applies to your scenario:**

Police Chief calls the state governor going:

"Holy ****, strange monsters that look like they are from the game Monster Smasher are appearing in our streets and murdering the citizenry and there isn't jack we can do."

Governor: "Calm down everything is going to be all right Ill handle this right away" Hangs up calls out to the secretary "We need to find a replacement police chief for so and so country quickly and recommend the current one for a **psych evaluation and drug test**."

**Chances are the police chief may be more politically inclined to realize this is a bad idea, just like in ST**

Comment: Would that necessarily work here? It sounds like the poster wants something obvious *within* the town: “anarchy,” “terrorism-scale criminal activity,” etc. On *Stranger Things*, the overwhelming majority of the community was ignorant, because either (S1) the attacks came from a creature that targeted only isolated individuals, and only briefly popped into the normal world, or (S2) the monsters were controlled by a guiding intelligence that kept things covert.

Comment: The only people aware of things were a handful of individuals with either no incentive or no *ability* for exposure (By the time there was a demo-dog in the freezer, they had bigger things to worry about, and a “good enough” plan for shutting down the operation. Had they not, things might have gone very differently indeed) . Or they were government forces devoted to keeping things secret. There weren’t monsters on Main Street, as it seems the poster wants in their game - that would have been virtually impossible to keep covered up.

Comment: @Obie2.0 that's a good point, the critical factor is you would need cooperation from local leaders like the police chief and mayor. If they both call the state then its game over. However, going back to the condition of the scenario, you are playing on political self-interest as means of containment. No one is going to believe videos (looks like CGI to me) no one is going to believe callers (mass prank). The key lies in the self interest and credibility of local leaders.

Comment: The thing is, people *would*. People believe Obama's Muslim, reptiles control the world, and blah blah blah.

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts...

Could be this community has its own secret.  Maybe the town is the HQ for a cult, and don't want outsiders around.  Maybe they're secret polygamists, and they're afraid of being persecuted.  Maybe it's a retirement community for various mafia groups (this might help with gun and rocket-launcher availability, too ;D ).

Hmm ... could be this town is seriously anti-technology (Amish?), and is in a remote location.  So it's very difficult for them to get the word out.

Say, does it have to be a whole town?  Might your setting be a boy scout camp?  Easier to explain a lack of cell phones there.  Though you'd end up with some *very unusual* badges being awarded...

Answer (score 2):

The *real* question is not why people disbelieve in supernatural events and monsters, but why the local authorities like police don't call for the army or whatever defense forces need to be mustered to deal with a supernatural monster outbreak. The answer is, of course, is about the balance of power.

Like the policy Mutually Assured Destruction (MAD) concerning nuclear weapons during the Cold War there will be a long held policy concerning outbreaks of supernatural monsters. This will be practised by both sides.

The 'leaking' of monsters into our world will not exceed a certain amount. This will be sufficient to tax the resources and capacity of local police and emergency services but not drastically exceed them. On the human side, our response will be limited to that of the local authorities, and in the event that massive amounts of additional human forces respond to a monster incursion the extradimensional floodgates will literally open with a veritable tsunami of monsters pouring into our world.

So when the local cops call the capital for additional support they will read the equivalent of whatever executive order of Act of Parliament or similar legal and governance instrument is needed to deal with these situations. Basically, it's you're on your own and the best of luck and we hope you survive.

PS: Don't bother to try and leave town. The Army will surround the township and anyone caught leaving it, will be be summarily executed.

PPS: This is for the common good of humanity. Best of luck again.

This also explains why cops and other services tolerate your heroes. They are freelancers who don't break the rules concerning official responses by humanity.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's an internal conspiracy, The town leaders are secretly responsible for the creation of the monsters, or perhaps they are the monsters or they've cut some sort of deal with them.  Whatever the reason the town leaders don't want the military or the government to get involved for fear that they will expose them.  So Instead of calling the military or the National Guard whenever the monster kills someone they Instead cover it up blaming it on some sort of animal attack or serial killer or something .
2. Another option is to give The monsters some sort of mine wipe ability to your monsters that can make people (That are not your heroes ) From remembering them after they leave .
3. But if you want something fairly simple then another easy option Is simple use fear and doubt . People are naturally skeptical specially now days about Fantastical things such as monsters, And people are naturally afraid has been labeled crazy.  Your police chief might simply be afraid That if he calls the National Guard and says  "Video game monsters are coming to life and killing people send everyone"  That he'll end up in a psychiatric facility .